# VC++ ATL DLL crashing -- possibly related to 32/64-bit issue

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, dll, 32bit-64bit, atl

I am having a problem with a 32-bit ATL dll that I have created---whenever I use the dll on a Windows XP (32-bit) computer it crashes without any warnings.  I think the issue is related to the version of Windows that I compiled the dll on, but I'm not sure.  Just a bit of history:

I initially developed the dll on a Windows XP (32-bit) box with Visual Studio 2008.  This version of the dll worked fine on Windows XP (32-bit) and Windows 7 (32-bit and 64-bit).  Then, I got a new development box with Windows 7 (64-bit) and Visual Studio 2010.  I converted my VS2008 project to VS2010, compiled it and it works perfectly on Windows 7 (32-bit and 64-bit) machines; however, when I run it on a Windows XP (32-bit), it crashes.

The funny thing is that I was able to successful regsv32 the dll on the XP machine, but when I ran dependency walker, it said that it was missing a bunch of files:

`api-ms-win-core-console-l1-1-0.dll

api-ms-win-core-datetime-l1-1-0.dll

api-ms-win-core-debug-l1-1-0.dll

api-ms-win-core-delayload-l1-1-0.dll

api-ms-win-core-errorhandling-l1-1-0.dll

api-ms-win-core-fibers-l1-1-0.dll

api-ms-win-core-file-l1-1-0.dll

api-ms-win-core-handle-l1-1-0.dll

api-ms-win-core-heap-l1-1-0.dll

api-ms-win-core-interlocked-l1-1-0.dll

api-ms-win-core-io-l1-1-0.dll

api-ms-win-core-libraryloader-l1-1-0.dll

...any many more of the same`

I copied all of these files from my development machine to the Windows XP box and now dependency walker tells me:

`Error: The Side-by-Side configuration information for "c:\documents and settings\poibri01\desktop\distributable\WERUI.DLL" contains errors. This application has failed to start because the application configuration is incorrect. Reinstalling the application may fix this problem (14001).

Error: Modules with different CPU types were found.

Warning: At least one module has an unresolved import due to a missing export function in a delay-load dependent module.`

I don't know where to go from here.  Can anyone help me?

**Edit**

1. Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 Redistributable Package (x86) is installed on the Windows XP machine.
2. I am compiling the DLL as a 32-bit Release (not Debug).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These dlls I think are [specific to Windows 7](http://blogs.mcafee.com/mcafee-labs/windows-7-kernel-api-refactoring), so they won't work on XP.  I suspect that either you have something in the manifest file that's specific to Windows 7 or you are specifying a minimum version in `_WIN32_WINNT` or `WINVER`, eg see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa383745%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

To see what's in the manifest file, use the [mt](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa375649%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) tool:

```
mt -inputresource:mydll.dll;#1 -out extracted.manifest
```

Comment: Thanks, the_mandrill...I think you're on to the solution.  In my project WINVER was set to 0x0600 (Windows Vista), so I changed it to 0x0501 (Windows Server 2003, Windows XP).  Here is the output of the manifest file:<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' standalone='yes'?>
<assembly xmlns='urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1' manifestVersion='1.0'>
  <trustInfo xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v3">
    <security>
      <requestedPrivileges>
        <requestedExecutionLevel level='asInvoker' uiAccess='false' />
      </requestedPrivileges>
    </security>
  </trustInfo>
</assembly>

Comment: However, when I run dependency walker on the dll, it's still referring to the Windows 7 dlls...do you have any ideas?

Comment: I forgot to add that the dll is still crashing on Windows XP.

Comment: I just commented everything out in the target.h file (the WINVER macro is defined here) and recompiled...still getting the same Windows 7 dependencies and crashing.

Comment: Nothing looks obviously wrong in the manifest.  I wonder if it's not your dll that has the dependency on these Win7 dlls, but rather another dll that you are depending on.  In the tree view of dependencywalker does it show that these are direct dependencies of your own dll or of another?  Also, are you absolutely sure it's a 32-bit binary?

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, "the_mandril"...I should have looked more closely at the dependency walker details.  Yes, these Windows 7 dlls are dependent on another dll that I am using...in this case, I'm using the Intel Math Kernel Library.  I'll have to figure out what I need to do to get the MKL to work on a Windows XP machine.  I am going to close this question and give you the credit because you identified the problem and part of the fix.  Thanks again for all your help...I really appreciate it! =)